# Ontologies with user interface

Tags: knowledge-base

I am working on the development of an ontology for my dissertation project. I have read plenty of resources and tutorials on how to develop ontologies, why are they useful and how to use them.

I've been trying to find examples of ontologies that include user interface such as textboxes, buttons etc. to study them for the development of my ontology. I checked databases such as ontoligua for similar projects but I didn't find anything to relate to.

I would be grateful anyone can help me with that.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want, but [ODASE](http://www.missioncriticalit.com/odase.html) looks something similar. (You might find publications if you search for `mercury lang ontology`.)